# Is it possible to have a non-standard page in the admin area?

Tags: wordpress

Client has a database table that is not a part of their wordpress environment but is alongside their other WP Tables (multiple departments access it). They'd like to use the wordpress admin interface to access a form so they can add content to this non-wordpress table (some other department pulls data from it).

Scenario:

1. The user logs into their WP Admin area
2. They click the link "Bob's Crab Shack" link from the left nav bar
3. They fill out the form and click save
4. The other department would have their own CRUD UI (not my concern).

Is this possible? If so, any guides or tutorials on how to set this up? Wordpress (PHP) isn't my primary coding language.

Comment: CORRECTION: PHP isn't my primary coding language.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress isn't a language ;-)

> Is this possible?

Sure, this isn't that hard to do.

1. Create an admin page: [Normal menu page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) or a [Submenu page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/).
2. Create the HTML form and PHP submit-logic.
3. Because all DB tables are in the same DB you can use `$wpdb` for DB processing (does al the heavy lifting for you), more info [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: Looking over the links you provided, this looks very promising. It seems like anything I need to do, I need to use a "plug-in" to do it. True?

Comment: What do you mean by plugin? All the links i provided are not about plugins, but how you can do it yourself (with PHP). You can create your own plugin for this, but i think it's also completely doable in functions.php. You don't need that many functions to create this. It kinda depends on how many form fields you have.

Comment: I may have misspoken, but in the first link (Normal Menu), there is a reference, `File: wp-admin/includes/plugin.php`. From that, I concluded a plugin was needed. Thanks for clarifying the functions file would be doable. I found another reference with an example. In working through the example code and your links, I think this is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: My bad, I clicked the up arrow instead of the checkbox. Rookie mistake. ;)